# how to slice text in django html?

Tags: python, django

I came across a problem in which I get the queryset displayed on the html. I cannot change the variable so i want to slice the output to only get a certain part.

for better understanding

```
<QuerySet [<User: testuser>]>
```

this is what my I see on my html page whereas I just want to see testuser

my html looks something like this

```
<p>{{ blogs.all }} blog{{ blogs|pluralize }} </p>
```

Comment: Isn't `blogs.all` returning a queryset here with all blog objects?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem no it isn't. its a college project and I dont think this is how the object is supposed to be used. but regardless can you help me with the output?

Comment: exactly what u want can you describe clearly

Comment: @user3411846 i want to display  ```<QuerySet [<User: testuser>]>``` as ```testuser```

Answer (score 0):

In Django, a `Queryset` object is the result of a query, and may refer to zero or more objects. The `Queryset` itself is meant to be iterated over or aggregated.

In the case of your template, I'm assuming `blogs` is intended to be a queryset, e.g. `Blog.objects.all()`. Just passing `Blog.objects` might make sense if you were using more than just `.all`, but you don't appear to be, and you seem to be assuming that `blogs` can be passed to [`pluralize`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize), in which case it needs to be a countable collection or a number. So I suggest you make sure the context value `blogs` contains `Blog.objects.all()` or something else that will produce a queryset.

So instead of this, which seems to be an attempt to show a blog count...

```
<p>{{ blogs.all }} blog{{ blogs|pluralize }} </p>
```

...try something like this. I've added iteration over the queryset since that seems to be causing you some confusion.

```
{% with blog_count=blogs.count %}
    <p>{{ blog_count }} blog{{ blog_count|pluralize }}</p>
{% endwith %}

{% for blog in blogs %}
    <p>{{ blog }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```